# Probleme in EntityType when editing form

Tags: forms, symfony-forms, symfony6

i have some select fields with EntityType, when my form is in 'Show View' i get the values from phpmyadmin but when i change it to 'Edit View' i get the list but the value is not selected by default. can anyone help me please.

one of my EntityType :

```
->add('SuiviPar', EntityType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'label' => 'Suivi Par',
    'attr' => [
    'class' => 'form-control',
   ],
   'class' => SuiviPar::class,
   'choice_label' => 'libelle',
   'choice_value' => 'libelle',
   'multiple' => false,
   'required' => false
])
```

my Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SuiviParRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SuiviParRepository::class)]
class SuiviPar
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $IDSuiviPar = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $Libelle = null;

    public function getIDSuiviPar(): ?int
    {
        return $this->IDSuiviPar;
    }

    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(?string $Libelle): self
    {
        $this->Libelle = $Libelle;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

i did try to set the value in the controller before form submission but it didn't work :

```
$suiviPar = $form->get('SuiviPar')->setData($immeuble->getSuiviPar());
```

please anyone help me!